# What is CSS alternative to <col width="0*">?

Tags: css

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Table</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<table border="1" style="width: 800px;">
    <col width="0*">
    <col>
    <col width="0*">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div></td>
        <td><div style="background: blue; color: white; text-align: center;">hello world</div></td>
        <td><div style="background: green; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to replace `<col width="0*">` with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example, you want to apply CSS to first and last column alone.So just add a reusable CSS class name to the column and define the style for it.

```
<col class="columnStyle">
<col>
<col  class="columnStyle">
```

In your CSS file:

```
col.columnStyle {
    width: 0px;
    /* specify required width here */
}
```

This will apply the specific width to only to those columns and not the middle one.

Comment: Quite simple. Too bad I didn't try it before asking this question.